# Is it possible without copy to pass std::vector<int> as param to fun that get std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>?

Tags: c++

I have such a method

```
void foo(std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> iVec){
....
}
```

I don't want to change this method, but I need to pass as param this vector `std::vector<int>`

As far as I understand this two vectors are taking the same memory... So, theoretical I can use method `std::move` to move this vector as is. But this vectors has a different size.. so... I don't know...

> One guy told me that it could be possible if change the function that it will get two int pointers, and so it could be possible.

But I don't understand what does it mean without a example... If someone could provide an example I really appreciate.

But anyway question still is: if is it possible to pass my vector as a function param that has another type. If yes, so how?

Fell free to ask

Comment: So if the passed in vector has 9 elements `iVec` should contains 3 arrays of length 3?

Comment: _I don't want to change this method_ - as long as this method takes an argument **by value** there's no way to avoid creating a copy.

Comment: @SombreroChicken yes

Comment: Because `std::array` is an aggregate type like an actual C-style array, you could possibly overlay it with a `std::vector<int>` but only in very narrow amount of cases. And it's really going to break the strict aliasing rule. Another problem is that the function takes its argument by value, and then you need to pass the exact type. To summarize: Don't try such things, copy the data into the correct container type, and call the function without worries. You could overload the function to do the copying and call the correct function.

Comment: That `one guy `  likely means to linearize your 2d vector (i.e transforming 2d into 1d).

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard does not guarantee that `sizeof(std::array<MyType, N>)==sizeof(MyType)*N`. That is, even though the elements of an individual `std::array` are contiguous, a `vector` of `array`s may not have the elements of the arrays evenly spaced. So there is no standard-compliant way of doing this, because the two vectors would *not* necessarily be "taking the same memory".

You could maybe get things to work with `reinterpret_cast` and such on your compiler. (`std::move` from a reinterpreted vector type will definitely *not* work, not in theory and not in practice.) This will not be portable or reliable or a good idea. You have three options: copy the data, change the source type, or change the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to change this method ...

But you should. If you make it work with iterators rather than the container, you will get more flexibility:

```
template <typename IT>
void foo(IT begin, IT end){
    ....
}
```

Now passing `begin` and `end` of whatever container is possible. However, if you want to go back to passing iterators to a `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>` you would have to invest some extra effort to get an iterator type that lets you iterate from `[0][0]` till `[size_x][size_y]`, but as the arrays all have size 3, this shouldnt be too complicated. And anyhow you should consider to use flat vectors instead of a 2D structure.